# Upgraded SQL 2008 to R2 but still have version 10.0.2531?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've upgraded SQL 2008 to R2 and the SQL Server Management Studio is showing 2008 R2, but whenever I connect to the SQL instance, it's displaying 10.0.2531 instead of 10.50.1600. Any idea on how to upgrade to the newer version?

Thanks.

Comment: You definitely ran the upgrade on the server hosting the instance, not just a PC running Management Studio?

Comment: Did you add a new instance rather than upgrading the existing one?

Comment: I think I upgraded the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

where exactly is displayed 10.0.2531?

run thiss against the server you say you upgraded:

> select
>   SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')

It should display 10.50.1600.1. If it doesn't then maybe you upgraded client tools or other SQL tool than SQL engine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue, when trying to attache an .mdf files that was created on another machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, to the SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my machine..

I did install 2008 (non-R2) and then 2008 R2 on my machine.

After spending hours googling to find a solution, eventually unsuccessful, I simply decided to download the installer 'SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe' from http://www.microsoft.com/en-AU/download/details.aspx?id=30438 and run it again, hoping it would solve (Windows 7 64 bit)

On the installation Wizard under 'Installation', I selected 'Upgrade from SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008' and continued to press Next until it disappeared (Obviously you will have to wait until it finish processiong each step).

That's it. I was able to attach the same file..